Can I add a Unity scene as a composable?
Currently I have a Unity scene running as a view in an activity (very similar to this solution).  As we're migrating to more composables, I'm wondering how to do that in this case.  Simplistically I could put a UnityPlayer in an AndroidView composable but I feel like that's missing a lot of context and lifecycle stuff that Unity depends on.  I tried a quick proof of concept using an AndroidView composable and didn't get very far.  Before spending too long trying to figure it out I thought I'd check if there's a known solution.  Has anyone tried this before and found a working solution?
Thank you!

Someone posted an answer yesterday and before I could approve it, it was removed.  So here's my version of the answer I was given yesterday.  To whoever posted it - thank you.
@Composable
fun UnityComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val unityPlayer = remember { UnityPlayer(context) }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            unityPlayer.quit()
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            unityPlayer.apply {
                val params = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                layoutParams = params
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            unityPlayer.settings?.getInt("gles_mode", 1).also {
                if (it != null) {
                    // Unsure if this is required, but I have it and it works
                    unityPlayer.init(it, false)
                }
            }
            view.windowFocusChanged(true)
        }
    )

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> unityPlayer.resume()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> unityPlayer.pause()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> unityPlayer.quit()
                else -> {}
            }
        }

        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}

